# How to import TypeScript types without using import type

Tags: typescript, ts-node

I have a simple TypeScript file that I would like to execute in ts-node. How would I import a type definition without using `import type`?
I expected `esbuild.BuildOptions` to be the type but this only generates an error.

```js
const esbuild = require('esbuild');

// this is what i would use in a module
// import type {BuildOptions} from 'esbuild';

const getConfig = (): BuildOptions => {};
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You can't import a type without the `import` keyword. `require` is typed as `(id: string) => any;` so that's not much help. But a type _only_ matters in typescript, and in typescript `import` is totally valid syntax. So your request doesn't make much sense.

Comment: `import * as esbuild from 'esbuild'` would probably work. But if you can do that then you can surely do `import type`, too.

Comment: My problem is specifically related to ts-node but I should have described it more precisely.

Comment: Why does `ts-node` make a difference here? `ts-node` doesn't really change how you need to write your typescript files. It's just a shortcut for compiling and running as one step.